# Does Exact Target support loading normalized data?

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-loader

We want to load the parent-child data from an Oracle database into ExactTarget using the data layout below. I'm looking if is possible to load in the normalized data format without converting the file into a normalized format like a flat record (all the child values in 1 record).

```
| ID  | Name | Preference    |
|-----|------|---------------|
| 123 | abc  | travel        |
| 123 | abc  | entertainment |
| 123 | abc  | food          |
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  That's no problem.

[Data Extensions](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/) are essentially database tables in the Salesforce Marketing Cloud.  You can define primary keys to accommodate the example you've provided.

You can use [Query Activities](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) to segment/transform your Data Extension data.

[Audience Builder](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/audience_builder/getting_started_with_audience_builder/) also provides a means to corral your normalized data -- but it's all Data Extensions behind the scenes.

Data can be loaded into Data Extensions using [Import Activities](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/import_activity/) or via [API](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/).